# iPad simulation for websites

Tags: ipad

I want to be able to display a website exactly as it would on different devices like an iPad. I have found several sites and programs (ipad peek/ adobe device centeral) but problem is that they don't do the stuff I really want.

for example iPad will reformat phone numbers and change how HTML displays. I want to be able to emulate that.

any ideas?

Comment: http://www.ipad-emulator.com/ doesn't work? No idea how faithful it is, granted. The Apple SDK is the best you'll get though, if you have a Mac.

Comment: @SirTapTap: ipad-emulator.com is just an iframe, the back/home buttons are just decoration.

Comment: Just thought I'd suggest, I didn't have any comparison since I don't own one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way I know to truly simulate an iOS device is to [register as an apple developer](http://developer.apple.com/programs/register/) and [download the iOS SDK](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action). It comes with an iOS simulator that will faithfully simulate both the iPhone and the iPad.

You will of course also need a machine running OS X, as the SDK  cannot be installed on a windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

I've also used http://www.testiphone.com/

It's not fancy, but I like that you can change the orientation of the device.